# Spring web application and asynchronous executions using thread pool

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, executorservice, forkjoinpool

I have a spring application which acts as a orchestrator whose responsibility is to  aggregate results from 6+ other spring web application whose results are mutually exclusively from each other, which meant that each service querying can be done in parallel. For this we used CompletableFuture with ForkJoinPool common pool with default pool size and since our only job in each thread is IO querying other services, we see thread pool exhaustion when there is huge load on system.

```
final List<CompletableFuture<List<Data>>> completableFutures = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> serviceToQuery.execute(...)).collect(Collectors.toList());
CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()])).join();
```

We have a peek of ~3000 request per second with each service request timeout set as 3 seconds using the circuit breaker. We have seen timeout also occurring with this setup.

I would be grateful if anyone could put light on how can it be tweaked for large number of queries or suggest any other approach and I looked into @Async also which works based on thread pool executor. Any pointers here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could use `ExecutorCompletionService` and pick up results from the completion queue. Aggregation can be done if you have a way to correlate all responses (may be a common uuid). Another approach could be to use the Spring Integration (SI) - there you could send the payloads to multiple channels, use service activators to process web application responses and finally use aggregate processors to aggregate results based on the correlation id and number of payloads.

Comment: @Ritesh Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely evaluate your suggestions in my context.